# reactJS : isomorphic app with flux

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, isomorphic-javascript

[React-flux-cart](https://github.com/scotch-io/react-flux-cart) . This example contains only client side code for react. How to make it isomorphic. What are the places where changes are required to include node and make it run as it is on server side also.

Comment: I haven't seen a really solid isomorphic-react-flux app boilerplate. Plenty of attempts, but there always seems to be something missing. For isomorphic-react, I like the [React Router Mega Demo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-mega-demo).

Comment: What kind of server (Ruby, Python, Java, .NET, PHP, Nodejs) are you using?

Comment: @khanetor I am using nodejs server. I want to know how to integrate it with the git repo I m referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already use NodeJS, then it should not be too hard.

I assume you already know how to call React.renderToString to render markup on the server. So what is left to be done is to render the markup that also display the data from the store.

If you look at [this store](https://github.com/scotch-io/react-flux-cart/blob/master/js/stores/CartStore.js) for example, the store data is defined at line #7

```
var _products = {}, _cartVisible = false;
```

What needs to be done is to set `_products` to some other data **BEFORE** you call `React.renderToString`. This is done via *Actions* in the Flux architecture (see how an action is invoked [here](https://github.com/scotch-io/react-flux-cart/blob/master/js/components/FluxProduct.react.js) at line #15).

So, before you call `React.renderToString`, you have to call this to populate your store:

```
var FluxCartActions = require('../actions/FluxCartActions');

var sku = 123123;
var update = {
  name: 'Scotch.io Signature Lager',
  price: 4.99,
  quantity: 1,
  type: '48oz bottle'
};

FluxCartActions.addToCart(sku, update);
```

Where `sku` and `update` can be any data you want.

For completeness, here is something you can do with ExpressJS

```
// server.jsx
var React = require('react');
var FluxCartActions = require('./reactCode/actions/FluxCartActions');
var FluxCartApp = require('./reactCode/components/FluxCartApp.react');
var app = require('express')();

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  var sku = 123123;
  var update = {
    name: 'Scotch.io Signature Lager',
    price: 4.99,
    quantity: 1,
    type: '48oz bottle'
  };
  FluxCartActions.addToCart(sku, update);
  var markup = React.renderToString(<FluxCartApp />);
  res.send(markup);
});
```

Note that this is a `.jsx` file, so use [babel require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) to enable JSX in NodeJS.

***This is important***. After you have your markup, you should clear your store before your next http request, otherwise, the previous data in your store will persist and visible for other requests.

You should take a look at [Alt](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt) because they make it easier to use Flux architecture than the implementation at Facebook. They also have functions such as `bootstrap`, and `flush` to help you populate your store, and reset your store without invoking an action or make any public accessor to your store. Alt is designed with server-side rendering in mind.